# Cucumber transform method doesn't trigger

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I try to use `Transform` method to convert string to symbol in my step definition.
But it doesn't trigger.

Here is my step:

```
Given(/^I log in to "(.*?)" project$/) do |project|
  #here I expect project to be symbol
end
```

Transform method

```
Transform /^I log in to "(.*?)"$/ do |project|
  project = :my_symbol
end
```

I put `Transform` right before step definition, but I still get the String instead of symbol.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [documentation for transforms](https://www.relishapp.com/cucumber/cucumber/docs/transforms), the example regular expressions are written without start- and end-of-string anchors. Putting the end-of-string `$` anchor in your transform expression prevents it from matching the step.

Try getting rid of the anchors in your transform, i.e.:

```
Transform /I log in to "(.*?)"/ do |project|
  project = :my_symbol
end
```

Also ensure that you're parenthesising the same content:

```
Given(/^(I log in to ".*?") project$/) do |project|
  #here I expect project to be symbol
end
```